# How to use forecast data in neural net when forecast produced periodically?

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, forecasting

I am considering how to structure a neural net problem where an input forecast (say, for chocolate production) is produced for 'k' time periods.  This forecast is produced every time period. and I would like to use this forecast in producing another forecast - the product of a neural net (say, for number of obese people) for k future time periods.

The issue is that for 1 time period beyond the present, 'k' forecast chocolate production forecasts are available for that point in time (each produced 1 time period apart).  For 2 time periods beyond the present, 'k-1' forecast chocolate production forecasts are available.  For 3 time periods beyond the present, 'k-2', and so on.

Given this setup, is there an effective way to setup a neural network solution employing all chocolate production forecasts to forecast number of obese people 'k' time periods ahead, knowing that for the 'kth' forecast point in the future, only 1 chocolate production forecast is available, while for the 'k-1'th forecast point ahead, 2 chocolate forecasts are available, and so on?

Should I just the latest production forecast, as overlapping forecasts might not add value?

Comment: any help from this link https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-multi-step-time-series-forecasting-of-household-power-consumption/.. 
if yes, you can read up and check if you have any issues

Comment: Thank you @venkatkrishnan although I don't see the direct connection.  I am attempting to answer the question: how can historical forecast data be incorporated into neural networks effectively for future time, where these historical forecasts change over time.